# How can i create a dynamically input fields using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, types, submit

I have created the input fields but when i click the first two ,it does well until when i request the third which comes between the first two and also other also comes between.can some help me please.
here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

    it to after "after-add-more" div class.
      $(".add-more").click(function(){ 
          var html = $(".copy-fields").html();
          $(".after-add-more").after(html);
      });

      $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
          $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
      });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Why is that now,its not even adding any more field.please i need more help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add-more").on('click', function(){ 
        var html = $(".copy-fields").clone();
        $(".after-add-more").after(html[0]);
    });

    $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
        $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class = "add-more">ADD</button>
  <div class = "after-add-more"></div>
  <div class = "copy-fields"><input type = "text" /></div>
</div>
```

Because you are trying to copy the html content of class .copy-fields, Use clone() instead html() and then use html[0] for insert after as following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add-more").click(function(){
        var html = $(".copy-fields").clone();
        $(".after-add-more").after(html[0]);
    });

    $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
        $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why is it not even adding any more field?please i need more help

Comment: thanks for your help but i have really tried it out but it has failed to add more input fields.please i need more help

Comment: Hey can you provide your html code, your html structure might be different.

Comment: I have edited my answer and include a working snippet code please review and compare the html code with yours.

Comment: @n.ssendawula do not post *your* code in *someone else's* answer. *Your* code belongs to *your* question, not to others'.